# Subset of hash keys in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I found myself writing a Perl script as a library for the specific format I'm working with is only available for this language. The script reads a CSV file and saves data into a proprietary format. I only need to save specific columns, not the whole dataset, so I figured a way to access columns by column names using the following code.

```
my $file = "test.csv";
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "$file: $!";

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({
  binary    => 1, # Allow special character. Always set this
  auto_diag => 1, # Report irregularities immediately
  });
$csv->column_names ($csv->getline ($fh)); # use header
while (my $row = $csv->getline_hr ($fh)) {
  print $row->{column_name};
}
```

Inside a while loop, I would like to get a hash which only has columns I need, not the whole record. I figured there's a way to do that with hashes like so:

```
@hash{qw(header_one header_two)}
```

But in my case `$row` is not a hash but a reference (am I right about that?), so I can't quite figure out how to achieve what I need. Appreciate some help! Thanks!

Comment: You want a hash ref slice.

Comment: If you've just picked up Perl to do this, your code is really very good, and you've done your homework. Nice to see a question like that. :)

Comment: see http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can use a reference (or expression that produces a reference) in any syntax by replacing the variable name with the reference in a `{}` block.  So:

```
@hash{qw(header_one header_two)}
```

would be

```
@{$row}{qw(header_one header_two)}
```

or

```
@$row{qw(header_one header_two)}
```

(the `{}` can be omitted if the reference is a simple scalar variable).

But that is just a hash slice returning the two values; if you want a key/value list, use a key/value slice (new in perl 5.20) instead:

```
my %slice = %$row{qw(header_one header_two)};
```